# sql query not working in unix shell script

Tags: unix

I am using shell variable in sql statement and that variable is string type.If I execute the below script I am  getting output as 'no rows selected' but when I execute same select query in sql prompt I am getting correct output.Even I tried by replacing $var with 'os' in script but still not getting needed output

```
var="os"
user="system"
pass="2451"
ou=$(sqlplus -s $user/$pass <<EOF
select login,subject from timetable where subject=$var;
exit;
EOF
)
echo $ou
```

Answer (score 0):

The executed statement in this case will be:

```
select login,subject from timetable where subject=os;
```

It will compare the row subject with the (non existant/system) var "os", which does not exists.

You must add brackets, depending on the dbms you use, like this:

```
select login,subject from timetable where subject=\'$var\';
```

Comment: its giving the following error  ORA-00911: invalid characteretable where subject=\'os\'

Comment: Try without backslashes